# Delete row which has more than X columns in a csv

Tags: bash, csv, awk, text-parsing

I need to delete all the rows in a csv file which have more than a certain number of columns.

This happens because sometimes the code, which generates the csv file, skips some values and prints the following on the same line.

Example: Consider the following file to parse. I want to remove all the rows which have more than 3 columns (i.e. the columns of the header):

```
timestamp,header2,header3
1,1val2,1val3
2,2val2,2val3
3,4,4val2,4val3
5val1,5val2,5val3
6,6val2,6val3
```

The output file I would like to have is:

```
timestamp,header2,header3
1,1val2,1val3
2,2val2,2val3
5val1,5val2,5val3
6,6val2,6val3
```

I don't care if the row with timestamp 4 is missing.

I would prefer a solution in bash or perhaps using awk, rather than a python one, so that I can learn how to use it.

Comment: Have you attempted to solve it yourself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can be done straight forward with `awk`:

```
awk -F, 'NF<=3' file
```

This uses the `awk` variable `NF` that holds the number of fields in the current line. Since we have set the field separator to the comma (with `-F,` or, equivalent, `-v FS=","`), then it is just a matter of checking when the number of fields is not higher than 3. This is done with `NF<=3`: when this is true, the line will be printed automatically.

#### Test

```
$ awk -F, 'NF<=3' a
timestamp,header2,header3
1,1val2,1val3
2,2val2,2val3
5val1,5val2,5val3
6,6val2,6val3
```

Comment: This is a pretty and smarter solution you could use instead of mine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just for curiosity, what if I wanted only the rows with exactly 3 columns? I tried and I cannot simply replace '<=' with '==' or '='.
If it is hard to be done, don't worry. It was just for curiosity.

Comment: @Paolo you were doing it properly! `awk -F, 'NF==3' file` is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following (do not omit to replace your file path and your max column):

```bash
#! /bin/bash

filepath=test.csv
max_columns=3

for line in $(cat $filepath);
do
    count=$(echo "$line" | grep -o "," | wc -l)
    if [ $(($count + 1)) -le $max_columns ]
            then
            echo $line
    fi
done
```

Copy this in a `.sh` file (*cropper.sh* for example), make it executable `chmod +x cropper.sh` and run `./cropper.sh`).

This will output only the valid lines. You can then catch the result in a file this way:

`./cropper.sh > result.txt`