# Remove lines in text file which contain fewer than 4 pipes

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file with data separated by 4 separate |
There are some problem lines in the file. These lines contain fewer than 4 pipes. 
The data in the problem rows is not needed and I want to run a command on the file which deletes any line which contains fewer than four pipes. I would also like to know how many lines were deleted afterwards so if this could be printed on the screen once the command is applied that would be ideal.

Sample data:

```
865|Blue Moon Club|Havana Project|34d|879
899|Soya Plates|Dimsby|78a|699
657|Sherlock
900|Forestry Commission|Eden Project|68d|864
```

Desired output:

```
865|Blue Moon Club|Havana Project|34d|879
899|Soya Plates|Dimsby|78a|699
900|Forestry Commission|Eden Project|68d|864
```

I have tried `awk '|>=3' file.txt` which didn't work. There is a lot of info out there regarding `awk`, some of which I found, but there's so much it makes it difficult to find exactly what I want to do due to its sheer volume.

Comment: I've tried      awk '|>=3' file.txt   but this didn't work

Comment: sample data and desired output added

Comment: See: [Delete row which has more than X columns in a csv](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29411952/3776858)

Comment: `awk -F'|' 'NF>3' file >new_file`

Comment: @Cyrus: `NF>4` if you require four pipes.

Comment: @rici: yes, good catch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To eliminate the lines:

```
grep '|.*|.*|.*|' file > newfile
```

To count the number of bad lines:

```
grep -cv '|.*|.*|.*|' file
```

That doesn't do the edit in place; you could do that with `sed` but it is often safer to do edits like this to a newfile, in order to avoid losing data if you make a mistake.

The first grep pattern matches any line with four pipe symbols. (By default, `grep` uses "Basic" regular expressions, in which you have to write the alternation operator `\|`. So you can use `|` as an ordinary character.)

The second invocation counts (`-c`) the number of non-matching (`-v`) lines.

Here's a simple sed solution:

```
sed -n -i.bak  '/|.*|.*|.*|/p' file
```

The `-n` option turns off automatic printing, so the command only prints the lines which match the pattern. (Again, by default, `sed` uses basic regexes.). The `-i.bak` option does the edit in place, creating a backup of the original with the name `file.bak`.

If you wanted to select lines with *exactly* four pipes, you could use `awk`:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF==5' file > newfile
```

which will set the filed separator to a pipe symbol and then select the lines with exactly five fields, which are the lines with four pipes.

A useful tool to count lines is `wc`:

```
wc -l file
```

will tell you how many lines are in file; if you count lines in both `file` and `newfile`, the difference will obviously be the number of deletions. You could do that computation in awk, too, but it's a bit wordier:

```
awk -F'|' 'NF==5{print;next}{del+=1}END{print del >>"/dev/stderr"}' file > newfile
```

Comment: The portable way to print to stderr in awk is `awk '...END{print del | "cat>&2"}'`.

Answer (score 2):

This will do:

```
sed -i.bak '/\([^|]*|\)\{4\}/!d' file
```

Or (as [Cyrus's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/61748476?noredirect=1))

```
sed -i.bak -E '/(\|[^\|]*){4}/!d' file
```

Or

```
sed -n '/^[^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|$/p' file > newfile
```

Or

```
sed -e '/^[^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|$/d' \
    -e '/^[^|]*|[^|]*|$/d' \
    -e '/^[^|]*|$/d' \
    -e '/^[^|]*$/d' \
    -i.bak file
```

This won't give you line count though. To get line count run `grep -cv '^[^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|[^|]*|$' file` on the original file as [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37102760/3744681) mentioned, or compare the line number before and after with `wc -l file` command

---

**Explanation:**

The first two `sed` matches loosely 4 pipes (not less but can be more) and the third one matches exactly 4 `|`  (not more or less).

The fourth `sed` matches exactly 3,2,1 and 0 pipes (`|`) and deletes those lines (in place) and prepares a backup file (file.bak) of the original.

Comment: or with GNU sed: `sed -E '/(\|[^\|]*){4}/!d' file`

Comment: @Cyrus : I wasn't sure if regex like `([ab]*)*` really works with sed. thanks for pointing it out.