# Script to find valid and invalid records CSV file

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, scripting

I'm trying to separate Valid and Invalid records in a CSV file based on a number of columns.
I went through the below SO question and seems to be doing the same.

[Delete row which has more than X columns in a csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29411952/delete-row-which-has-more-than-x-columns-in-a-csv)

However for my case delimiter is ^H, so tried below approaches.

```
awk -v FS="\b" 'NF==3' sample.csv >> output.csv
awk -v FS="\\^H" 'NF==3' sample.csv >> output.csv
awk -v FS="\\cH" 'NF==3' sample.csv >> output.csv
awk -v FS="^H" 'NF==3' sample.csv >> output.csv
```

However, nothing worked for ^H delimiter.

Moreover, in the previous SO question, they are capturing the valid records(to output), I want to capture both and invalid records into two different files.

```
Sample.csv

timestamp,header2,header3
1^H1val2^H1val3
2^H2val2^H2val3
3^H4^H4val2^H4val3
5^H5val2^H5val3
6^H6val2^H6val3


Valid.csv

timestamp,header2,header3
1^H1val2^H1val3
2^H2val2^H2val3
5^H5val2^H5val3
6^H6val2^H6val3


Invalid.csv

timestamp,header2,header3
3^H4^H4val2^H4val3
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: Why are you treating `^H` as part of valid file content?

Comment: because that's delimiter of the CSV file @Inian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. It is basically looking for 2 conditions 1st is checking if Number of fields are 3 then place output into `Valid.csv` if number of fields are more than 3 then place output into `Invalid.csv` output file.

```
awk -F'\\^H' 'NF==3 && FNR>1{print > "Valid.csv"} NF>3 && FNR>1{print > "Invalid.csv"} FNR==1{print $0 > "Valid.csv";print $0 > "Invalid.csv"}' sample.csv
```

Adding non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk -F'\\^H' '
NF==3 && FNR>1{
  print > "Valid.csv"
}
NF>3 && FNR>1{
  print > "Invalid.csv"
}
FNR==1{
  print $0 > "Valid.csv"
  print $0 > "Invalid.csv"
}' sample.csv
```

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13, I tried the above one. One observation is header is missing in both valid and invalid files. I didn't the FNR one, Could you please it, as the number of columns may change for different file want to make sure, I understand the command.

Comment: @user805, yes if column may vary you could change conditions, for headers, let me fix it now.

Comment: @user805, could you please check now my edited solution and let me know then?